# Monitor DocumentDb RU usage

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to programmatically monitor the Request Unit utilization of a DocumentDB database so we can manually increase the Request Units proactively?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a call you can execute to see the remaining RU, since they're replenished at every second. Chances are that the time it would take to request and process the current RU levels for a given second would return expired data.

To proactively increase RU/s, the best that can be done would be to use the [data from the monitoring blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics).

Comment: Is the RequestCharge in the ResourceResponseBase a measurement of RU usage? If so, I could imagine determining overall RU utilization from that.

Comment: Regarding the azure monitor blade - which signal measures RU utilization? Total RU seems to be a sum over the last period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try below steps:

1. Use azure cosmos db `Database - List Metrics` rest api from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/database/listmetrics).
2. Create [Azure Time Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) to execute above code in schedule(maybe every 12 hours). If the metrics touch the threshold value,send a warning email to yourself.

Comment: I just looked at the metrics and didn't see any defined for RU utilization. Would it be possible to call out which metric(s) are surfaced for RU?